# Angular generate componente using templateUrl and styleUrls by default

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I working on a internal component library, but when I generate a componente using:

```
ng g lib component-name -p ui
```

I get the following on the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: "ui-component-name",
  template: `
    <p>
    input works!
  </p>
  `,
  styles: []
})
```

But I would like to know if there's any flag I could use to generate my components using `templateUrl` and `styleUrls` instead of `template` and `style`, because I have to create a lot of components and I don't want the team to change `template` to `templateUrl` and `style` to `styleUrls` and then generate the respective files. So, there is any way to generate something like this:

```
@Component({
      selector: "ui-component-name",
      templateUrl: 'ui-component-name.html',
      styleUrls: [ui-component-name.scss]
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is generate your lib as you just did, and for the other components you can run this command `ng generate component mycomponent --project=your-lib-name --module=your-lib-name.module.ts --export` (https://angular.io/cli/generate#component)

Comment: But I would like to generate a npm package, do you know if I could make it with the componente generator?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand it this way, I don't think this is possible, in the doc there is no such param (https://angular.io/cli/generate#library)

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate it

Comment: All of your components will go in seperate libs ? or they'll all go in the same lib ?

Comment: All go in the same library, so I just realize that using ng g lib component-name -p ui if not the best approach, but what would you suggest?